# What is the difference between update_post_meta and update_postmeta hooks?

Tags: hooks, post-meta, core

I am working on an enhanced revisioning system, to create a log file for all changes made by users and/or algorithms concerning metadata attached to specific post types.

While I am perfectly aware that `update_post_meta` works for all post types, while `update_postmeta` just works on post, my question is not dependent on the post type, and it also does not just cover the `update` part, as it is the same for `updated`, `delete`, etc.

After inspectiong `wp-includes/meta.php`, I found the previously mentioned hooks to get my stuff done, but this raised a questions for me.

The section in the core is this one - line 215 in Version 4.4.2:

```
foreach ( $meta_ids as $meta_id ) {
    /**
     * Fires immediately before updating metadata of a specific type.
     *
     * The dynamic portion of the hook, `$meta_type`, refers to the meta
     * object type (comment, post, or user).
     *
     * @since 2.9.0
     *
     * @param int    $meta_id    ID of the metadata entry to update.
     * @param int    $object_id  Object ID.
     * @param string $meta_key   Meta key.
     * @param mixed  $meta_value Meta value.
     */
    do_action( "update_{$meta_type}_meta", $meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $_meta_value );
}

if ( 'post' == $meta_type ) {
    foreach ( $meta_ids as $meta_id ) {
        /**
         * Fires immediately before updating a post's metadata.
         *
         * @since 2.9.0
         *
         * @param int    $meta_id    ID of metadata entry to update.
         * @param int    $object_id  Object ID.
         * @param string $meta_key   Meta key.
         * @param mixed  $meta_value Meta value.
         */
        do_action( 'update_postmeta', $meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );
    }
}
```

So there is a hook for `update_post_meta`, `update_comment_meta`, and `update_user_meta`. Directly after that another hook is called - just for the posts table, named `update_postmeta`, working almost exactly the same way, with the only difference being that the `maybe_serialize()` data of the meta_value is passed.

Line 204:

```
$_meta_value = $meta_value;
$meta_value = maybe_serialize( $meta_value );
```

At first I thought that the second hook is there for backward compatibility, but both of those were introduced in 2.9.0. [`update_postmeta`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/update_postmeta) and [`update_{$meta_type}_meta`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/update_%7B$meta_type%7D_meta)

Looking a little bit further, I also found another answer by me, three years ago, where this topic also came up, but this was not the main point.

Am I missing something here?

Is this backward compatibility after all - and has just been moved to `meta.php` in 2.9.0? Or is there any real reason to have both of those? For me, the actions hooked to the `update_post_meta()` function could easily `maybe_unserialize()` the data, if needed, so I really do not see the point of having both.

Looking forward to your input!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They were both introduced in version 2.9, but were done so in different files.

`update_postmeta` went into [`/wp-admin/includes/post.php`](http://svn.automattic.com/wordpress/tags/2.9/wp-admin/includes/post.php)

While...

`update_{$meta_type}_meta` went into [`/wp-includes/meta.php`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/version/2.9/wp-includes/meta.php)

It was only later that `update_postmeta` was shifted into `/wp-includes/meta.php`.

So I believe it was for backward compatability, where by because the `update_postmeta` hook was always receiving the value of `maybe_serialize()` then it should continue to do so, despite later being moved into `/wp-includes/meta.php`.

Furthermore, which you may already know, but for the sake of others reading, the `update_postmeta` hook returns data from the `$_POST['meta']` superglobal and key which holds data from the [custom fields panel](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields).

Could this just have been a poor design decision? Looks like it.

*I thought I recalled some other reason surrounding this very question in relation to double serialization of data, however I could be getting mixed up with something else.*

Interestingly, if you store already serialized data in the Custom Field UI textarea, WordPress will serialize it again before storing it, which supports the notion of backward compatability in relation to:

- https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12930
- https://nacin.com/2010/04/18/wordpress-serializing-data/

Note: **this answer is not neccessarily complete**.

Answer (score 0):

As noticed in Wordpress Codex, **add_post_meta** inserts new postmeta associated to a post. If provided parameter "unique" as true, will check for existing key with same name. If exists, bypass it, if not, create and assign value

**update_post_meta** will update metadata and create new key and value pairs, if provided meta_key  not exists.

**What is the best to use?** It depends. update_post_meta fits the most situations, but sometimes add_post_meta will get the work done if you need to add metadata in restrited environments (shared hosting, for example).

Please read for more info:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta and 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta